# Slow laptop loading

Tags: performance, freeze, hardware-failure, reboot, lubuntu

A few days ago my laptop started to slow loading. It has Lubuntu installed. Further more when it goes to sleep it can not be returned and I can see only black screen.
Sympthoms: slow loading, when lubuntu loaded and I can see login screen my mouse moves like with delay in 3-4 seconds, also it can just freeze and then I need to reboot laptop (but I need to do it a few times). After a few hard reset(by holding power button for long time) grub showed up but arrows on keyboard did not work.

What could be wrong. Is there tool for testing hardware in such cases?

Also I month ago I broke my touchpad when I was cleaning fans. I broke the place in touchpad where cable from motherboard was plugged in. And then I got it repaired. And repair gay sad that he had to solder some not ordinary cables. So could it be the reason of problems?

Laptop specs:
packardbell p5ws0 core i3
lubuntu 15

Comment: If you include your laptop's details and the events leading to the issue, that would help us answer better.

Comment: Yes. I updated topic with computer specs.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

I'm not sure if it is real solution. But computer started working as usual after I installed X.Org open source drivers for my nvidia card instead of proprietary (in software & updates). Computer now do not freeze and wakes up after suspending as usual.